After upgrade to 24.04 How to enable 3rd party sources back that were disabled in upgraded process?
Im on kubuntu with Kubuntu software center "Discover"
In settings i think in 22.04 was option to see sources that were added after installing deb packages with their 3rf party sources.
I just did upgrade to 24.04.
I got notification in process that some 3rd party sources removed. Now i want to enable. Where basic user can do that?
VLC and OBS and Kdenlive is lost- removed. How did that happen? was it then when I was asked also to remove packages? Why was VLC and OBS and Kdenlive a normal app also removed if its not from 3rd party?
After upgrade i was able to install vlc and OBS again natively.
im on kubuntu. maybe i can install something else so i can see sources and again enable software soucres while its not implemented in Kubuntu software center "Discover"

Befor enabling any third party sources it's your responsibilty as the administrator of the system to check, if a third party repository is valid for your version of Ubuntu. You don't want to run in trouble like The repository xxx doesn't have a release file which will prevent you from keeping the system proper updated.

@mook765 is it possible to enable? that was the question. where? cant find place

The package you need is software-properties-qt, this package is recommended by the package plasma-discover and should be installed by default in your system. If it is not installed already, run
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-qt

You should find an icon in your application launcher in the category System named Software Sources.
Use the checkboxes in the Other Software-tab to disable or enable repositories.

Of course, you cannot enable sources that have been removed you'd have to re-add the source first.
